# C# - Format event log query with multiple arguments

Tags: c#, event-log

I have the following event log query where I need to filter by event ID and specific date range for the Time Created.  Here is what I current have:

```
var _PRINTINGDOCUMENTEVENTID = "307";
var startTime = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10);
var endTime = System.DateTime.Now

var query = string.Format("*[[System/EventID={0}] and [System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= {1}]]] and [System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime <= {2}]]]", _PRINTINGDOCUMENTEVENTID, startTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"), endTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"));)

var logQuery = new EventLogQuery("Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational", PathType.LogName, query );

var reader = new EventLogReader(logQuery);
```

I get the following error when I try to debug the event log query:

> The specified query is invalid

Here is what the `query` value looks like while debugging:

> "*[[System/EventID=307] and [System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime >=
>   2016-03-28T22:51:23.9082575Z]]] and [System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime <=
>   2016-03-28T23:01:23.9092576Z]]]"

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: You can use EventViewer to create a query and view the output on the XML tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to determine the correct format for filtering by event id and a date range for TimeCreated

```
var eventId = "307";
var startTime = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10);
var endTime = System.DateTime.Now;

var query = string.Format(@"*[System/EventID={0}] and *[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= '{1}']]] and *[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime <= '{2}']]]",
    eventId, 
    startTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"),
    endTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried surrounding your formatted DateTimes with ticks?

```
and [System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= '{1}']]]
```

Comment: Looks like you may have an extra bracket at the beginning of your format string.  Try taking off the first bracket, or adding on at the very end.

Comment: I needed an asterisk in front of the each filter element